# How can I monitor wildfly version 20 on zabbix 4.0?

Tags: wildfly, zabbix

I have done everything possible from my end.
OS Linux data is coming from server.
but data of wildfly (i.e heap thread etc.) is not coming.
does anyone have template of wildfly 20?

Answer (score 0):

There are several solutions widely available on the internet

- [Zabbix-JBoss-Agent](https://github.com/marcanpilami/Zabbix-JBoss-Agent)
- [Zabbix_wildfly_eap_jboss_monitoring](https://github.com/hermanekt/Zabbix_wildfly_eap_jboss_monitoring#old-template)

WildFly (formerly JBoss) is a Java application and can be monitored with [JMX agent](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/4.0/manual/config/items/itemtypes/jmx_monitoring)

---

I would strongly recommend upgrading to a newer version of Zabbix, as version *4.0* will become unsupported on October 31, 2021.

Comment: Hi @NamanBansal, If you find my answer helpful, you may want to consider [accepting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)